# How to configure an Android Virtual Device to work on my home computer

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-emulator, memory-management, android-virtual-device

My computer confguration is:
Processor: Interl Celeron 1.8 MHz
RAM: 1 GB

When I've run Android emulator it stuck in a cycle, because of lack of memory. How to setup it to run on my computer? Is there any chance?
intepenit

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same configuration on my laptop, but it works very very slowly. I prefer using the phone to debug my apps. Only thing you can do with no real device is to disable all unuseful applications and services in your OS. This might help a bit, but anyway you won't get the speed you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run your applications (no debug) then you could try [YouWave](http://www.youwave.com/)